# Bootstrap does not produce even spans

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have stripped everything from my page, just a link to a fresh bootstrap file. Still, even with my spans adding up to 12, they all display different widths in both firefox and chrome. What in the world could be going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <input type="text" class="span6" placeholder="Pre">
        <input type="text" class="span6" placeholder="Pre">
    </div>  
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <input type="text" class="span6" placeholder="Pre">
        <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Sufix">
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Pre">
        <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Pre">
        <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Sufix">
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <input type="text" class="span6" placeholder="Pre">
        <input type="text" class="span6" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using row-fluid so you would generally need to use either the bootstrap combined css or include the bootstrap responsive css.

Also with forms when including multiple grid inputs on the same line you also need to warp them in `<div class="controls controls-row">` to get the padding all working correctly.

In my tests I still noticed the odd layout blip at certain screen widths. For me I get the most consistent results for your form when using non-fluid rows.

See http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/zhsks/ with this all working for you (non-fluid row)

See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms for more details about the controls-row div

Good luck!