# Bootstrap form spans not even

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a form and would like to ensure that all the spans line up and are square.  But even though all the spans will add up to 12, each row is a different width.  Is just the way it is, or am I doing something wrong?

```
<div class="container ">

                            <form class="well form-inline">
                                <div class="controls controls-row">  
                                    <label class="span1" for="input01">
                                        Prefix
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span1" id="input01" placeholder="Dr."><label class="span1" for="input02">
                                        First Name
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span3" id="input02" placeholder="John">
                                    <label class="control-label span1" for="input03">
                                        last Name
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span3" id="input03" placeholder="Doe">
                                    <label class="control-label span1" for="input04">
                                        Suff
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span1" id="input04" placeholder="Jr.">
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls controls-row">  
                                    <label class="span1" for="input01">
                                        Company
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span5" id="input01" placeholder="Sample LLC">
                                    <label class="span1" for="input02">
                                        Title
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span5" id="input02" placeholder="Director of Samples">
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls controls-row">  
                                    <label class="span1" for="input01">
                                        Address 1
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span5" id="input01" placeholder="Address Line 1">
                                    <label class="span1" for="input02">
                                        Address 2
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span5" id="input02" placeholder="Address Line 2">
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls controls-row">  
                                    <label class="span1" for="input01">
                                        Cntry
                                    </label>
                                    <select class="input-medium span2 countries" data-country="US"></select>
                                    <label class="span1" for="input01">
                                        City
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span2" id="input02" placeholder="City">
                                    <label class="span1" for="input02">
                                        St/Prv
                                    </label>
                                    <select class="input-medium span2 states" data-country="US" data-state="CA"></select>
                                    <label class="span1" for="input01">
                                        Zip
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span2" id="input02" placeholder="City">
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls controls-row">  
                                    <label class="span1" for="input01">
                                        Email
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span5" id="input01" placeholder="you@yourdomain.com">
                                    <label class="span2" for="input02">
                                        Confirm Email
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span4" id="input02" placeholder="you@yourdomain.com">
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls controls-row">  
                                    <label class="span1" for="input01">
                                        Phone
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span3" id="input01" placeholder="">
                                    <label class="span1" for="input02">
                                        Cell
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span3" id="input02" placeholder="">
                                    <label class="span1" for="input02">
                                        Fax
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="span3" id="input02" placeholder="">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

screen shot here: http://www.flickr.com/photos/92503149@N07/8409032538/in/photostream

Comment: Anyone?  Any help would be super appreciated...

Comment: So is this related to another question you asked?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469605/bootstrap-does-not-produce-even-spans

Answer (score 0):

You only posted a snippet, so I do not know how you integrat the form in the rest of your page, but a `row-fluid` could help:

```
<form class="well form-inline row-fluid">
```

I tried it out, looks much nicer already.

More hints:

- some labels are missing the class `control-label`. This is overall important due to the line-height adjustment that `control-label` does.
- depending on the complete width of the form, some labels might not fit into `span1` on one line (was the case in my quick tests)
- and a general design hint: the last line with 3 label/input pairs breaks the layouting a bit. Usually, you try to stick to certain vertical positioning.

Hope this helps